# Facebook Login on in Windows

Tags: facebook, windows-services

Is it possible to authenticate to facebook without using one of their web page dialogs?  I'd like to build a windows service that runs in the background and does a few FB tasks periodically for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what you're trying to do you should only really need a valid token which you can generate at the developer portal under your application settings.  Make sure you enable offline_access to generate a long lasting token.